# Prometheus query in Grafana for counting the number of metrics received during last N minutes

Tags: prometheus, grafana, metrics

Let's assume that my Prometheus "info" metrics (called `my_metric`) look like:

```
my_metric_info{company_id="sample_company_id_1", system_id="sample_system_id1"}
my_metric_info{company_id="sample_company_id_1", system_id="sample_system_id2"}
my_metric_info{company_id="sample_company_id_1", system_id="sample_system_id3"}
my_metric_info{company_id="sample_company_id_1", system_id="sample_system_id1"}
my_metric_info{company_id="sample_company_id_1", system_id="sample_system_id2"}
my_metric_info{company_id="sample_company_id_1", system_id="sample_system_id1"}
```

I'm trying to accomplish two things:

- I want to create Grafana panel showing the count of metrics received for a specific company during, say, last 30 minutes. Ideally it should be "last N time units" where time unit is second, minute, hour, day, etc.
  For the sample dataset above (assuming they were all received during last 30 minutes) it should just show number 6, that's it.
  Tried this: `rate(my_metric_info{company_id="sample_company_id_1"}[30m])` but it doesn't even finish and keeps rotating. Is it even the one that I need?
- I want to create Grafana panel showing the table with two columns (A and B). Column A is `system_id` and column B is the count of metrics received for that `system_id` during last 30 minutes (again, ideally during "last N time units").
  For the sample dataset above, the table should show this:

  ```
     -------------------------
     sample_system_id_1      3  
     sample_system_id_2      2  
     sample_system_id_3      1
  ```

  Tried this: `count by(system_id) (rate(my_metric_info{company_id="sample_company_id_1"}[30m]))` but the table's column A shows timestamps `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` instead of system Ids, so definitely incorrect.

Thanks